# Listening to multiple child window closed event, can't check if window was closed for multiple child

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The parent of a page is listening to several child windows close event. If any child window is closed, then the page is going to do a postback in a grid view. Therefore the parent page is not reloaded and the window_dictionary does not 'reset'. In the following code, I'm adding the window object as a value to a global JavaScript dictionary. The object contains the key (combination of "clickedRow"+ record id), and the value is the window object.

It works perfectly fine for the first window close event, but no for the following window close events. For example, if I open two child windows, I can close the first one and the __dopostback() method is going to be called, but when I close the remaining window then __dopostback() is not called.

I assume there might be a problem with the setInterval call. However; I've been stuck for a while and I can't get this to work as expected.

For every window closed, I want to do a postback.

**Code**

```
    var openedWindows = {};

    setInterval(checkIfWindowIsClose, 40);

    function openThisWindow(popLoc, attributes, id) {
        var winInst = window.open(popLoc, attributes, id);
        openedWindows["clickedRow" + id] = winInst;
    }

    function checkIfWindowIsClose() {
        var id = "";
        for (var i in openedWindows) {

            if (openedWindows[i].closed) {
                // i is the id of your window and here you know that your window with id i has been closed
                // here remove also the window from the object otherwise you will keep also the instance of the closed one
                console.log(i);
                delete openedWindows[i];
                id = (' ' + i).slice(1);
                id = id.replace("clickedRow", "");

            }
        }
        if (id !== "") {

            __doPostBack('upInspectionList.UniqueID', id.toString());
            id = "";
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: checkChild returs nothing , so what would be the value of timer.

Comment: @manikantgautam, I'm not sure I understand the goal of the question. How can I ensure that I can listen to all the added windows in the JavaScript dictionary since I can only listen to it for a single window in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object where you store your opened windows. 
With an interval cycle inside your object in order to detect if a window has been closed.
I tried it and it works fine, of course change this example with all your needs. 
In this way you need just one timer instead of creating every time a new one.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id="button-1" onclick="openThisWindow(this);">Button 1</button>
    <button id="button-2" onclick="openThisWindow(this);">Button 2</button>
    <button id="button-3" onclick="openThisWindow(this);">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var openedWindows = {};

setInterval(checkIfWindowIsClose, 4);

function openThisWindow(el) {
    var winInst = window.open("http://www.google.it");
    openedWindows[el.id] = winInst;
}

function checkIfWindowIsClose() {
    for (var i in openedWindows) {
        if (openedWindows[i].closed) {
            // i is the id of your window and here you know that your window with id i has been closed
            // here remove also the window from the object otherwise you will keep also the instance of the closed one
            console.log(i);
            delete openedWindows[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, but remember I do have multiple child windows and that's why I'm adding those objects to a global dictionary. I shouldn't have added JQuery in my initial post, so I apologize. However; your suggested solution won't work because the child window refreshes itself every second....

Comment: Nope I mean to completely remove your timer. With this solution every window you open will have the before unload event, which will make the post passing the right name.
But do you mean that your main child windows may open other child windows on cascade?

Comment: Thank you so much for refactoring your solution to JavaScript. I tried the implementation, but it didn't work. It didn't force the postback. From the parent I can generate multiple children, is not a cascade that from a child I can open a sub-child. What I want is a way that I can listen to all the windows opened (from the parent), and that if I close two out of three opened child windows, then force a postback on every close event. That's why I have the global variable, to keep track from the parent page to all the opened child windows.

Comment: ok I did few tests locally, I am changing the answer with another approach you could try, let me know if it can suit you. To my side this works fine and it detects correctly if a popup has been closed

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, but when I post back the grid view it resets everything. Including the openedWindows dictionary.  That's why I can't keep track of the second close event. It first postback, then I have a clean new global variable. My assumption was wrong, but your answer is good. I need to figure out a way to make openedWindows persistent.

Comment: Sure it does because you reload the js associated to the page. I don't know your business case and what you are trying to do, but does the local storage suit you? maybe you can store there your dictionary. But again, I don't know what you are trying to do. 
If the solution worked fine for you except for the problem of reloading the page, which has not to do with keeping track of opened windows, please mark the answer as correct so it can be useful for other people with the same issue